# Movie Trailer Api result id html not responsive output

Tags: php, xml, api, responsive-design, movie

http://trailerapi.com/api/api.php?user_trailer_limit=10&language=en 
link

```
$api_url_content='http://trailerapi.com/api/api.php?user_trailer_limit=10&language=en'; 
if(!$xml = simplexml_load_file($api_url_content))
{
echo “Error”;
}else
{

foreach( $xml as $film ) {
$movie_name= $film->name,
$movie_poster =$film->poster;
$movie_id=> $film->did;
$movie_description=$film->description;
$movie_year=$film->year;
$movie_producer=>$film->producer;
$movie_imdb=$film->imdb;
$movie_cast=$film->cast;
$movie_genre=$film->genre;
$movie_trailer='<iframe src=”http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video    /’.$film->did.'” width=”720″ height=”480″ frameborder=”0″ allowfullscreen=”allowfullscreen”></iframe>';

INSERT INTO `trailer`.`trailers` (`id`, `name`, `description`, `poster`, `cast`,`embed`) 
 VALUES (NULL, '{$movie_name}', '{$movie_description}', 
'{$movie_poster}', '{$movie_cast}', '{$film->did}');
}

}

<?php $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM trailer Where id='{$_GET['id']}' Limit 1");
$fetch=mysql_fetch_array($query); ?>
<div style="width:100%">
<iframe src=”http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/<?php echo $embed; ?>” frameborder=”0″ 
allowfullscreen=”allowfullscreen”></iframe>
</div>
```

html code div responsive and player is not Responsive

How to Responsive Embed Code

output :

```
<div style="width:100%">
<iframe src=”http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/ x2pgbqt” frameborder=”0″ 
allowfullscreen=”allowfullscreen”></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should be like that

```
<iframe src="http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x2pgbqt" frameborder=”0″ 
allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" width="100%"></iframe>
```